# SQL table query result first and second row and compare them

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
WITH CTE AS  
(
    SELECT 
        userId, COUNT(*) AS cnt, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS RowNum
    FROM
        tableA A WITH(NOLOCK)
    WHERE 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR, A.Createdon, 23) >= CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE() - 7, 23)
    GROUP BY 
        userId
)
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN (SELECT CAST(((SELECT CAST((SELECT cnt FROM CTE 
                                         WHERE RowNum = 1) - (SELECT cnt FROM CTE WHERE RowNum = 2) AS DECIMAL(10,2)))
                /
               (SELECT CAST((SELECT cnt FROM CTE WHERE RowNum = 2) AS DECIMAL(10, 2))) * 100) AS DECIMAL(10, 2))) > 100 
           THEN 1 
           ELSE 0 
    END
```

I'm comparing the first result with second result and if first result is %100 bigger than second result my code returns true,

The code is working but how can I make it faster and prettier?

EDIT:
Changed date part to:

```
 A.Createdon >= CONVERT(date,DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE()))
```

It went like from 25 seconds to 10 seconds, Can I make it faster.
thanks to commenters.

Comment: Why are you converting a date to VARCHAR before comparing? That makes the query unnecessarily slow.

Comment: @TheImpaler CONVERT(VARCHAR, A.Createdon, 23) >= CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE() - 7, 23) do you mean here? If so I want to make query for 1 week result.

Comment: Juts calculate the beginning and end of the week then. Also  you can use `LAG` to get the previous row's data. Sample data and expected results would help immensely

Comment: Then why not just do `A.Createdon >= CONVERT(date,DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE()))` @questAd ..? Why convert your column at all?

Comment: Do you have a "good" reason for using the `NOLOCK` hint too?

Comment: @ThomA, I changed  to this A.Createdon >= CONVERT(date,DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE())),
went like 25 seconds to 10 seconds thanks :) Can I make it faster though :)

Comment: Sample data, and expected results, would help us help you, to start with. WE can't run your query.

Comment: @ThomA well I m using the rowNumber for selecting, first and second row, maybe There would be easier way of doing it, I feel like It makes code slower.

Comment: What do you want to do if you have three or more rows?

Comment: @Charlieface It's always have more than 2 rows, I want to check the first two as I'm doing In my code.

Comment: OK lets have sample data and expected results, as asked

Comment: Aside: From [`VarChar(n)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017): "When _n_ is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration statement, the default length is 1. When _n_ is not specified when using the CAST and CONVERT functions, the default length is 30." The best practice is to _always_ specify a length.

Comment: The _actual execution plan_ will provide information about the performance of the query, e.g. whether an index is being used. It's a common place to start analyzing performance issues. Please see [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/) for a way to include an execution plan in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is completely untested because we lack sample data and expected results, but perhaps this would be more performant:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT TOP (2)
           UserId,
           COUNT(*) AS Cnt
    FROM dbo.TableA --NOLOCK removed, no good reason provided for its use
    WHERE Createdon >= CONVERT(date,DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE()))
    GROUP BY UserId
    ORDER BY Cnt DESC)
SELECT CASE WHEN MAX(Cnt) = MIN(Cnt) * 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END --Check if MAX is exactly double MIN
FROM CTE;
```

Comment: Looks like OP actually wants `MAX(Cnt) >= MIN(Cnt) * 2`

Comment: I read their description *"if first result is %100 bigger than second result"* as needs to be 100% larger (i.e. double the size), @Charlieface . That sample data and expected results we're missing would likely tell us what they *actually* wanted.

Comment: OP is using `> 100` (on a percentage) in their code

Comment: Yeah, their description and code don't align, @Charlieface , not a lot I can do about their ambiguity unfortunately.